# Can't get reverse dns working

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, reverse-dns

I've set up bind9 before but now I apparently made a misconfiguration somewhere & I don't see it. DNS is working fine, reverse DNS not. I know I have to reverse the IP range to get it working. Underneath my config. Can some kind soul show me where I messed up?

**/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones**

```
// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912

zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

    zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};

zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" in {
    file "/etc/bind/db.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
    type master;
    check-names ignore;
};

zone "XXX.local" in {
    file "/etc/bind/db.XXX.local";
    type master;
    check-names ignore;
};
```

**/etc/bind/db.XXX.local**

```
$TTL 2D
@               IN SOA          fw.XXX.be.  root.fw.XXX.be. (
                                2011071000      ; serial
                                3H              ; refresh
                                1H              ; retry
                                1W              ; expiry
                                1D )            ; minimum

XXX.local.              IN NS           fw.XXX.be.

XXXApp01                A               192.168.10.6
XXXApp02                A               192.168.10.7
XXXHistorian            A               192.168.10.8
XXXShared               A               192.168.10.9
XXXFujitsuLaptop        A               192.168.10.3
fw                      A               192.168.10.254
```

**/etc/bind/db.10.168.192.in-addr.arpa**

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
10.168.192.in-addr.arpa  IN SOA  fw.XXX.be root.XXX.be. (
                                3          ; serial
                                604800     ; refresh (1 week)
                                86400      ; retry (1 day)
                                2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
                                604800     ; minimum (1 week)
                                )
                        NS      fw.
$ORIGIN 10.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 1200       ; 20 minutes
254             PTR     fw.XXX.be.
$TTL 604800     ; 1 week
006             PTR     XXXApp01.XXX.local.
007             PTR     XXXApp02.XXX.local.
008             PTR     XXXHistorian.XXX.local.
009             PTR     XXXShared.XXX.local.
003             PTR     XXXFujitsuLaptop.XXX.local.
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    allow-query { localhost; 192.168.10.0/24; 192.168.160.0/24; 10.0.0.0/16; 10.0.50.0/24; 10.0.51.0/24; };
};
```

Huge thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Jord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing your NS record(s) in the reverse zone file (I couldn't see the "IN" bit). Also, you probably don't need to pad the last octect out with zeros.